# Multiple rows in header for Table with Table Sorter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to javascript and jquery, web programming in general, so please bear with me.

I have integrated table-sorter in a table but I cannot figure out how to extend this by allowing sorting on multiple rows per header. For example, if i have the following table (assume the UPPERCASE letters in the first row are Headers with sorting capability using table-sorter):

```
   |-------------------|
   |  NAME  |   GENDER |
   |        |    AGE   |
   |-------------------|
   |  Anne  |    F     |
   |        |    14    |
   |-------------------|
   |  Gina  |    F     |
   |        |    13    |
   |-------------------|
   |  Mike  |    M     |
   |        |    12    |
   |-------------------|
```

If i would click on AGE in the header the table will look like

```
   |-------------------|
   |  NAME  |   GENDER |
   |        |    AGE   |
   |-------------------|
   |  Mike  |    M     |
   |        |    12    |
   |-------------------|
   |  Gina  |    F     |
   |        |    13    |
   |-------------------|
   |  Anne  |    F     |
   |        |    14    |
   |-------------------|
```

I want to allow this sorting availability for all 3 headers, and when clicked, each should only take in consideration it's parameter.

- The headers can have multiple rows, it doesn't mean that they only will have one or two. Though, I will know that when the table is created.

So far I have gotten to this: http://jsfiddle.net/mrroboti/FepfW/

This the CSS file that the tablesorter uses:

```
   table.tablesorter thead tr th, table.tablesorter tfoot tr th {
           background-color: #e6EEEE;
           border: 1px solid #FFF;
           font-size: 8pt;
           padding: 4px;
    }
    table.tablesorter thead tr .header {
        background-image: url(bg.gif);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center right;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

What will I have to do to tell CSS to allow me to add multiple headers in one cell, and make it possible for all rows inside a header to be able to sort.

Thank you,
Any direction you give me for this will be very helpful because I am super stuck.

**UPDATE ON THE FIDDLE:**
http://jsfiddle.net/mrroboti/FepfW/7/

Added the new headers but still cannot figure out how to do this.

Comment: I can't for the life of me figure out what "multiple rows per header" means.

Comment: The gender and age, in the tables that i have sketched are two rows, in a header. A multirow header.....

Comment: Why can't you have gender and age in seperate columns? Are gender & age meant to be independantly sorted, ie Click on age to sort by age, click on gender to sort by gender? Are gender & age in seperate cells and do they need to be? Perhaps provide some HTML on how you envisage marking up the table. Your fidle doesn't really demonstrate this.

Comment: This is just a sample, my table has too many columns, if i were to do that it would be huge.

Comment: @JonP here is an updated fiddle.

Comment: Can you make your fiddle represent your problem better, e.g, use Name | Gender | Age etc. Also you cant nest a `tr` in a `td` you need to use the `rowspan` attribute

Comment: @JonP here is the most up to date fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mrroboti/FepfW/ 

This basically explains my problem. Run it, and try to sort, you will see what happens.
You will be able to sort with the Name, but everything will get messed up. Also, you will not be able to sort with Gender, only Age (or vice versa). THanks!

Comment: Also there will be no basic solution for this. If it can be done, custom data parsers and headers will need to be used. The simplest solution is 1 column for each set that needs to be sorted. Re-evaluate your table, is every column really required? Is sorting on every column really required?

Comment: I can't have one column per header, it's unnacceptable. The table will have 32 fields, and it will be too big for the screen. The users would have to scroll to the right to be able to look at everything.

Comment: The problem is that the talble sorter plug in is **not** designed to work with `rowspan` I'm not saying it can't be done, but I doubt there is a simple solution. You other option is to sort server side, using a page refresh or ajax, again not neccesariliy simple.

Comment: @JonP I was tyring to improve from Ajax...and page refresh...and wanted to use this instead. Those are slow.

Answer (score 0):

In short, it's not possible to use tablesorter this way as it never intended to do such because it does not conform to any web standard.

However, you can do the following to get this done.  Write your own plugin or modify the tablesorter code.  I would choose the latter.